# my new flutter project failed to run on my device with exception

Tags: flutter, plugins, build, version, flutter-plugin

- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0']

> Failed to apply plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'.
> No signature of method: FlutterPlugin.allprojects() is applicable for argument types: (FlutterPlugin$_apply_closure2) values: [FlutterPlugin$_apply_closure2@31c4d98d]

i simply want run my app and i had previously built project those are also showing the same error.
i am using
Flutter 3.16.0
Tools • Dart 3.2.0 • DevTools 2.28.2

Answer (score 0):

may be this was because of "Depriciated Gradle plugin application",try replacing the existing plugin application in android/settings.gradle, with

pluginManagement {
...
includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")
}

plugins {
id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
...
}

Comment: should i update the gradle plugin or what because the plugins are already set as          pluginManagement{ includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle") }
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
}

Comment: Ensure your Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin versions are compatible with your Flutter version. Refer to the official documentation for recommended versions: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/pubspec

or else try 

flutter clean and then flutter run to rebuild.

Comment: i have compared my settings and environment with other android studio in another device which runs a new flutter project perfectly. They all matches but my android studio is throwing the exception

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).